# SSRS Arrow Indicators Start and Ends

Tags: reporting-services

I have a difficult time figuring out the ranges for SSRS indicators.

I'd like the following logic:

- Green Arrow = Any value greater than 6%
- Yellow Line = Any value between 0% and 5%
- Red Arrow = Any negative value.

I have the following currently, but it does not work.

[image: screenshot]

Any assistance would be appreciated.

EDIT----
Current output show below to highlight problem:
As you can see the negative percentage shows with a yellow dash. I'd like any negative value to be red, only zero through 5% should be yellow, and anything higher than 5% should be green.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information why it doesn't work? Example records, report XML, SQL script, etc.

Comment: @aduguid Edit, and added picture of current output.

Comment: Can you provide enough data and report XML to reproduce the issue? You can use a `SELECT FROM VALUES` for an example dataset and then post the report XML.

Comment: @aduguid Thanks for your assistance! I was actually able to figure out the answer, and I've posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the "States Measurement Unit" selection within the Values and States properties on the indicator. I had it set to percentages, but the values I was using were numeric. Setting the "States Measurement Unit" to to Numeric and having my value evaluate to percentages solved the issue. The following is my end result, negative percentages to 0 are red, percentages between 1 and 5 are yellow, and percentages between 6 and 900 are green:

[image]